# IIS Rewrite rule - if path does not have query string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, iis-6, iis-8

How do I write IIS Rewrite rule `if path does not have query string and any capital letter exists in path then redirect to same path with lower case`?

e.g.
 
http://localhost:62871/Second.aspx/Test?X=Y 
redirects to: http://localhost:62871/second.aspx/test?X=Y

Following rule works but it lower cases the querystring too:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `URL` contains the entire url - so `ToLower` is lower casing the entire url.

To get the desired behaviour you need to create the `action`'s url manually from multiple server variables.

Available variables include `{HTTP_HOST}`, `{PATH_INFO}` and `{QUERY_STRING}`, you can then apply the lowercase function to whichever variables you require.

When creating the final url you also need to include the seperators `:`, `/`, `?` between the variables to get a valid url.

See this page for quick overview of variables: https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-parts-available-to-url-rewrite-rules

See here for full rewrite module docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference